# Edit profile with validation on password field

Tags: php, symfony

I added some validation rules on User entity because I had some errors when users didn't fill all the field, especially the password field.

User Entity :

```
    /**
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=8,
 *     max=4096,
 *     minMessage="Votre mot de passe n'est pas assez long.",
 *     maxMessage="Votre mot de passe est trop long."
 * )
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="Veuillez renseigner un mot de passe.")
 */
protected $plainPassword;
```

It's working as expected with the registration form. With the edit form though, I always have a validation error on the password field. My edit form doesn't contain the password field. How can I make it work ?

Edit Form :

```
        $builder->add('username'         , IntegerType::class)
            ->add('nom'              , TextType::class)
            ->add('prenom'           , TextType::class)
            ->add('email'            , EmailType::class)
            ->add('dateNaissance'    , DateType::class)
            ->add('telephonePortable', TextType::class)
            ->add('adresse'          , TextType::class)
            ->add('codePostal'       , TextType::class)
            ->add('ville'            , TextType::class)
            ->add('enabled', ChoiceType::class)
            ->add('photo', FileType::class)
            ->add('plainPassword', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('submit');
```

Comment: Are you using a bundle like FosUser ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using FosUserBundle for my User entity

Comment: The plainPassword is just a virtual field in order to generate the password field, who is hashed... You cannot retrieve the data... Did you know that ?

Comment: No, I didn't know that. So I have to put my validation rules on the password field instead of the plainPassword field ?

Comment: Why do you need to get the password on your edit form, even if it's hidden ? If the user wants to change password, fosUser has a route in order to perform it....

Comment: I just understood what you mean. I put the plainPassword field in the form to test if there is any difference but with or without this form field, I have the same validation error.

Comment: @KristenJoseph-Delaffon Validation should be on plainPassword, your example is correct. Try adding validation groups for each field & forms (eg: "registration", "edit")

Comment: @IwanWijaya Thank you, it's working with validation groups. I didn't know this feature.

Comment: @IwanWijaya put the solution in an answer, not in a comment. Then Kristen will accept your answer in order to resolve the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem over here. I solved this asserting NotBlank in the form builder, not in Entity.

My UserType (form used for creating and editing)

```html
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($options['newUser']) {
            $builder
                ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                    'type'           => PasswordType::class,
                    'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
                    'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
                    'required'       => true,
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotBlank()
                    ]
                ))
                ->add('cpf', TextType::class)
            ;
        }

        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
                'empty_data' => '',
            ))
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'empty_data' => '',
            ))
            ->add('dateOfBirth', DateType::class, array(
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            ))
            ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'multiple' => true,
                'choices'  => array(
                    'User'          => 'ROLE_USER',
                    'Administrator' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                ),
            ))
            ->add(
                'userAddress', UserAddressType::class, array(
                'data_class' => UserAddress::class,
            ))->getForm();
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
            'data_class'      => User::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'newUser'         => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my entity is:

```
 /**
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;
```